# Neovim, change background of all splits not just one

Tags: lua, neovim

I want to have a transparent background in my neovim. And so far I have found this:

`vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "Normal", {guibg=NONE, ctermbg=NONE})`(I have this placed all the way at the bottom of my init.lua) (and I also have this purely vim way: `hi Normal guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE` that also work)

which works up until I open a new split. (I am using NeoTree which opens a new split with a file tree). Then it only works for the NeoTree and not for the other splits.

This is how it looks normally as I want:

[image: This is how it looks normally as I want]

(The darkening of the background is because of my Terminal settings)

When I open neotree(or any other split):

[image: When I open neotree(or any other split)]

I have tried different auto scripts that were supposed to change the background of inactive splits. It didn't work and I got loads of error messages when creating new splits. Tried many different versions none of them helped